# Postgres order by select columns

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering if there was a simple way to do something like this...

```
SELECT
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3,
    ...
    column_n
FROM my_table
ORDER BY
    column_1 ASC,
    column_2 ASC,
    column_3 ASC,
    ...
    column_n ASC;
```

But making it cleaner such as:

```
SELECT
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3,
    ...
    column_n
FROM my_table
ORDER BY SELECT LR ASC;
```

I know this doesn't work but I hope the idea makes sense. Essentially I was the table to be ordered all ascending with the importance of the order going from left to right (LR).

Is there anything like this out there? Or is it a stupid idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `ORDER BY` is summarised in [this manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-order.html). There is no version that allows you to specify multiple columns in one expression.

The manual does mention, but not give an example of, "column numbers", which can make life a bit easier. `ORDER BY 1` means "sort by the first column/expression in the `SELECT` list", so you can write this:

```
SELECT
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3,
    ...
    column_n
FROM my_table
ORDER BY
    1 ASC,
    2 ASC,
    3 ASC,
    ...
    column_n ASC;
```

So you only need to know the *number* of columns, not repeat the full names or expressions for each.

Comment: Yes but this does not cover if two new columns are added at the end for example and one forgets to place them in the order by also. I knew about the column numbers, just seems like a feature that would be good to have.

Comment: @KevinOrriss Yep, I realise this isn't quite what you asked for, but I think it's as close as you're going to get. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. There is not such construct: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-order.html